# accessing variable from the child dialog

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

I have a child dialog. I initiate other child dialog.
In the second dialog i have the following code for list box.
I need to access the m_selcomponents in the first child dialog. Itried to access this like
     dlg->m_selcomponents. But it's getting null. How can i do this?  Thank You for help.

```
int count = m_OutList.GetCount(); 

for ( i = 0; i <m_OutList.GetCount(); i++)
    {
        m_OutList.GetText( buf[i], text );
        m_selcomponents->Add(text);

    }
MSelCFLCompDlg *SelCflCompDlg= new MSelCFLCompDlg(&allcomponents, &m_cflcomponents,m_FileDecimal,this) ;
```

if(SelCflCompDlg->DoModal()==IDOK) { selectedcomponents.Append(*SelCflCompDlg->m_selcomponents); }

```
MSelCFLCompDlg::MSelCFLCompDlg(CStringArray *all, CStringArray *sel,int, CWnd* pParent /*=NULL*/)
    : CDialog(MSelCFLCompDlg::IDD, pParent)
{
    //{{AFX_DATA_INIT(MSelCFLCompDlg)
        // NOTE: the ClassWizard will add member initialization here
    //}}AFX_DATA_INIT
    m_allcomponents = all;
    m_selcomponents = sel;

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create the child dialog box, pass a pointer to the parent dialog box to the child dialog box constructor. If you show us a bit more of your code I can perhaps explain in a bit more detail.